# Using symmetry to prune DFS tree for graph coloring problem

Tags: graphs, search-trees, colorings

I am working on the graph coloring problem. I came up with the following.

Let $S^L$ be the set of all colorings with $N$ colors for a graph with $L$ nodes. This is shorthand notation for $\{1, 2, 3, ..., N\}^L$ - a string of $L$ characters each belonging to a set $S = \{1, 2, ..., N\}$.

I noticed that we can prune the search tree if we apply the symmetry. For instance coloring $1211$ is the same as coloring $2122$. Idea is that if we take the colorings where first appearances of elements are in order, all others can be mapped to them. I provide the proof below.

Let us make this more formal. So for instance in coloring $12113$, first color to appear from left to right is $1$, then $2$, then $3$, which is in order. To help us define this let $\psi$ be the function that finds the first coccurance of color $c$ in the coloring $s$, that is $\psi(c, s)$. So for example $\psi(2, 1321) = 3$

Define $\Omega = \{ s \in S^L : i < j \Rightarrow \psi(i, s) < \psi(j, s) \}$. This is the set of colorings all other coloring can be mapped to.

Mapping is easy to find. Let $s \in S^L \land s \not \in \Omega$. We just sort the $\psi(k, s)$ and map each $k$ to its position in the sorted array. This way first element that occurs will be replaced by $1$, second by $2$ etc.

Now what my algorithm does is just traverse the $\Omega$ and print out the  feasible solution with least colors used it found. This seems not to work for all cases since it finds suboptimal solutions. I checked my implementation it seems to exactly capture the algorithm described.

So my question is: **Is the reasoning I provided above correct and does the $\Omega$ represent the entire $S^L$ and it is sufficient only to traverse $\Omega$ to find optimal coloring?**

I think my reasoning is correct. I have been twisting my head with this for quite some time and it is frustrating since I can not find the mistake. I programmed the coloring generator where I check that each coloring can be mapped to one from the base for certain $L$.

Comment: Your $\Omega$ contains every optimal solution, so there's a bug.  To debug: (1) Try small instances until you hit one that reports a suboptimal solution $X$.  (2) Take a known optimal solution $X^*$ and reorder its colours so that they obey $i < j \implies \psi(i, s) < \psi(j, s)$: call this $X^<$.  (3) You generate the elements of $\Omega$ in some order; determine the first iteration $k$ that your program generates a solution $X' > X^<$.  (4) Rerun with a breakpoint set for $k-1$ iterations.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks I feel better now knowing it is a bug and not flawed algorithm since I started doubting everything in the algorithm. Also dataset that it first fails on is too big to debug but I will try to generate some smaller one that fails.

Comment: Brendan McKay has representations of all (unlabeled) graphs on up to 10 vertices here: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html.  This can be useful for finding small counterexamples when debugging :)